# React array being sorted before the function is being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I was working on displaying the steps to sorting an array and trying to render out the different steps in react. When I call my bubble sort function, the array is already sorted after I click the button.

**Creating my state variable:**

```
  const [arr, setArr] = useState(resetArr())

  function resetArr() {
    return new Array(10).fill().map(() => {
      return ({
      num: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
      eval: false
    })})
  }
```

**Bubble sort function**

```
  function bubbleSort() {
    const history = [];
    const sArr = arr.slice();
    let len = sArr.length;
    for (let i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      for (let j = 1; j<=i; j++) {
        if (sArr[j-1].num > sArr[j].num) {
          const temp = sArr[j-1].num;
          sArr[j-1].num = sArr[j].num;
          sArr[j].num = temp;
        }
        history.push(sArr);
      }
    }
    console.log(history)
  }
```

**Button and return**

```
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="arr-container">
        {arr.map((item, idx) => 
          <div key={idx} className="arr-item">
            {item.num}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => bubbleSort()}>Bubble</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

**Console log for history**

```
0: Array(10)
0: {num: 0, eval: false}
1: {num: 3, eval: false}
2: {num: 9, eval: false}
3: {num: 18, eval: false}
4: {num: 33, eval: false}
5: {num: 41, eval: false}
6: {num: 53, eval: false}
7: {num: 65, eval: false}
8: {num: 94, eval: false}
9: {num: 99, eval: false}

1: Array(10)
0: {num: 0, eval: false}
1: {num: 3, eval: false}
2: {num: 9, eval: false}
3: {num: 18, eval: false}
4: {num: 33, eval: false}
5: {num: 41, eval: false}
6: {num: 53, eval: false}
7: {num: 65, eval: false}
8: {num: 94, eval: false}
9: {num: 99, eval: false}
```

Any help is appreciated, I am completely stuck on why it's working like this.

Comment: Can you post this as a Code Sandbox/

Comment: where is the other console.log? the code only shows one after the sorting is done, so I don't see the problem in the output if that's the result of clicking twice

Comment: @dwjohnston https://codesandbox.io/s/bubble-sort-39clz

Comment: @diedu the history is an array that looks somewhat like this, [[{num:0, eval:false},],], I am pushing to history at every stage of the for loop

Comment: You're pushing the same array to the history array on each loop.

Comment: @dwjohnston yes but it's already sorted and it should be getting updated each time at the if statement before I push. Or am i seeing this wrong?

Comment: Just as a bit of feedback for your question, this isn't anything to do with react at all. You could post just the 'bubbleSort' function and have the same problem. That makes it a lot easier for people ot understand what's wrong with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand object references in JavaScript and programming languages in general.

As an example:

```js
const array = []; 

const someObject = {
  a: "foo"
};


array.push(someObject); 
someObject.a = "bar"; 
array.push(someObject); 

console.log(JSON.stringify(array, null,2));
```

This doesn't print:

```
[
  {
    "a": "foo"
  },
  {
    "a": "bar"
  }
]
```

it prints:

```
[
  {
    "a": "bar"
  },
  {
    "a": "bar"
  }
]
```

Because in that first push to the array, you aren't pushing the object *as it is at the time*, you are pushing *a reference to the object*.

In this scenario, when you later change the objects `a` property, (you *mutate* the object) that value changes in the array.

This kind of confusion is why people like to avoid property reassignment like this, why *immutable programming* is a thing.

Your code basically has the same problem.

You are pushing the same array to the history array each time it loops, and then you are later mutating that array.

If you change your history.push line to this:

```
history.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sArr)));
```

This solves your problems.

What the parse-stringify does is just clones the array object, ie, it creates a *new* array object.

Comment: I didn't even think of this... I was so confused, thank @dwjohnston

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be helpful at all, but I decided I might as well link it: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-haze-98ipt?file=/src/App.js)!

I thought it would be nice to have the rendering portion implemented so it would be easier to see what is happening to the data.